# A question on the exact value

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization, symbolic

Could anyone help me find the exact value of

```
Maximize[Min[1, 1 - Cos[2 x], 1 + Cos[2 x], 1 - Cos[2 x - 2 y], 
  1 + Cos[2 x - 2 y], 1 - Cos[2 y], 1 + Cos[2 y], 1 - Sin[2 x], 
  1 + Sin[2 x], 1 - Sin[2 y], 1 + Sin[2 y]], {x, y}]
```

by Mathematica or rigorous reasoning or proof? Thanks a lot

Comment: Your comments to the answers indicate that you are not looking for the exact value found by Mathematica or rigourous reasoning or proof, but for a rigourous proof from Mathematica or rigorous reasoning, which is different. math.stackexchange might be better suited for your needs.

Answer (score 6):

Your function has many symmetries:

```
f[x_, y_] = Min[1,
                1 - Cos[2 x],
                1 + Cos[2 x],
                1 - Cos[2 x - 2 y], 
                1 + Cos[2 x - 2 y],
                1 - Cos[2 y],
                1 + Cos[2 y],
                1 - Sin[2 x], 
                1 + Sin[2 x],
                1 - Sin[2 y],
                1 + Sin[2 y]];

f[x + π/2, y] == f[x, y] // FullSimplify
(*    True    *)

f[x, y + π/2] == f[x, y] // FullSimplify
(*    True    *)

f[π/2 - x, π/2 - y] == f[x, y] // FullSimplify
(*    True    *)

f[y, x] == f[x, y] // FullSimplify
(*    True    *)
```

From these, plus a graphical representation

```
DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, π/2}, {y, 0, π/2}, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

the maxima are clearly at $(x,y)=(\frac{3\pi}{8},\frac{\pi}{8})$ or any point equivalent by the above symmetries:

```
f[3*π/8, π/8]
(*    1 - 1/Sqrt[2]    *)
```

Comment: Thank you for the non-rigorous answer. But could you produce the exact value by the Mathematica command in the question or do you have any rigorous proof for the exact value? Thanks.

Comment: @Steiner you are on the wrong forum for rigorous math. Please ask on [the math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: But I paid nearly $2000 for Mathematica, which should not be just for numerical calculations, and since the function has many symmetries as you said, why couldn't Mathematica produce the exact value for it? Thanks.

Comment: Mathematica is a tool, not an oracle.

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, y_] = 
  Min[1, 1 - Cos[2 x], 1 + Cos[2 x], 1 - Cos[2 x - 2 y], 1 + Cos[2 x - 2 y], 
   1 - Cos[2 y], 1 + Cos[2 y], 1 - Sin[2 x], 1 + Sin[2 x], 1 - Sin[2 y], 
   1 + Sin[2 y]];
```

Plotting,

```
Plot3D[f[x, y],
 {x, -π/2, π/2}, {y, -π/2, π/2},
 PlotRange -> All,
 Exclusions -> None,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

[`Maximize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize.html) is unable to find the maximum because the function is not smooth. Using [`NMaximize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMaximize.html)

```
max = NMaximize[{f[x, y], -π/2 < x < π/2, -π/2 < y < π/2}, {x,
    y}]

(* {0.292893, {x -> -1.1781, y -> -0.392699}} *)

max2 = ReplacePart[max, {
   1 -> RootApproximant[max[[1]]] // Simplify,
   2 -> (max[[2]] /. (t_Real :> π*RootApproximant[t/π]))}]

(* {1 - 1/Sqrt[2], {x -> -((3 π)/8), y -> -(π/8)}} *)

max[[1]] == N[max2[[1]], 15]

(* True *)

({x, y} /. max[[2]]) == ({x, y} /. max2[[2]])

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you for the non-rigorous answer. But could you produce the exact value by the Mathematica command in the question on a supercomputer or any other symbolic computation software or tools or do you have any rigorous proof for the exact value? Thanks.

Comment: Evaluate `(Sqrt[12803520241] - 45779)/230028 < 1 - 1/Sqrt[2]`

Comment: I am not asking about the irrational number in the LHS, but could you produce the exact value by the Mathematica command in the question on a supercomputer or any other symbolic computation software or tool, or do you have any rigorous proof for the exact value? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

The reduction of trig functions to polynomials does the job:

```
Maximize[{Min[1, 1 - cx, 1 + cx, 1 - cx*cy - sx*sy, 1 + cx*cy + sx*sy,
1 - cy, 1 + cy, 1 - sx, 1 + sx, 1 - sy, 1 + sy], 
sx^2 + cx^2 == 1 && sy^2 + cy^2 == 1}, {sx, cx, sy, cy}]
(*{1 - 1/Sqrt[2], {sx -> -(1/Sqrt[2]), cx -> 1/Sqrt[2], sy -> -(1/Sqrt[2]), cy -> -(1/Sqrt[2])}}*)
```

The rest is left on your own.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just wondering, do you know the procedures, steps or algorithms in Maximize[{Min[1, 1 - cx, 1 + cx, 1 - cx*cy - sx*sy, 1 + cx*cy + sx*sy,
1 - cy, 1 + cy, 1 - sx, 1 + sx, 1 - sy, 1 + sy], 
sx^2 + cx^2 == 1 && sy^2 + cy^2 == 1}, {sx, cx, sy, cy}] in Mathematica? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Steiner: No, I don't know it.

Comment: @Steiner  You need to replace `cxcy` with `cx*cy` or `cx cy`.